# Node.js module loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am currently building a web app with Node and I am curious as to how Node loads its required files or modules.

I am using express for view and server config, however I am finding that all the Node examples (I know express offers an MVC example) don't really conform to the general MVC pattern. I am also aware that Node is not necessarily suited for MVC, but bear with me, because I like MVC.

If you consider the following route declaration, it would be effective to use this as a controller, since here you can control the request and response logic:

```
module.exports = function (app) {

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.render('index', { layout: false });


});
```

To try and follow an MVC architecture I have effectively divided the routes up into its relevant paths in effect creating controllers. However whenever I have a different route file it must contain its own set of required modules. For example:

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
```

I would then declare the required route files in the app.js or server.js file that holds the server config settings.

I am wondering whether splitting up the routes like this would slow down the application since I am unaware of how Node loads its modules. If it is loading as per needed then surely this implementation must slow it down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Required modules are only loaded once and then [cached](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), so feel free the break up your app into as many modules as needed to cleanly organize your app.  If you have 20 files that call `require('mongoskin')`, that module is still only loaded once.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the node.js [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> Modules are **cached** after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be
>   executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it,
>   "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive
>   dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.